# Display most recent line by key

Tags: text-processing

I've got a file containing a bunch of fields:

```
12345 some values here
67890 other values maybe
12345 different values here
```

...etc.

I'd like to display the *most-recent* line for each key. The output should be as follows:

```
67890 other values maybe
12345 different values here
```

In the output, the keys should be unique, and the values (the rest of the line) should be the most-recent seen for that key. I don't particularly care about the resulting order of the keys.

How can I do this using GNU (or POSIX) tools?

Comment: just to put a finer point on it, "most recent (matching) line" means "last (matching) one in the file"?

Comment: Yeah; "most recent" = "tailmost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ data[$1] = $0 } END { for (key in data) print data[key] }' file
```

This would save the data of each line in the array `data`, keyed on the first field.  When another line with the same first field is found, the old data for that key is simply overwritten.

At the end, all data in the array is outputted.

More memory efficient:

```
sort -k1,1 -s file |
awk 'NR > 1 && $1 != key { print data } { data = $0; key = $1 } END { print data }'
```

Here, we first sort the file on the first column only, using a stable sorting algorithm (`-s`).  Using a stable sorting algorithm means that lines with the same key won't change position relative to each other in the output of `sort`.

The `awk` code then only has to keep track of the "current key" and the latest data for that key, and to print that data when the key changes (and at the end).

Comment: Given that my keys are fixed length, I'm guessing that I can actually just use `uniq -w N` instead of `awk` in the second example?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I'm not on a GNU system, so I'm not sure what `uniq -w` does.  My guess would be "no" though.

Comment: `uniq -w N` only looks at the first `N` characters for uniqueness. Given that the `sort -k1,1` groups the lines together, I was hoping that `uniq` would be enough; turns out that "matching lines are merged to the first occurrence". There doesn't appear to be a way to change this behaviour (i.e. last occurrence).

Answer (score 0):

I would reverse the file, output each line the **first** time it is seen, then reverse the output

```
tac file | awk '!seen[$1]++' | tac
```

Comment: If it was actually a file, this'd work well. It's actually (a `zfgrep` over) a whole bunch of files, so the `tac` would generate (I guess) a bunch of ... stuff that needed buffering somewhere. But, were that not the case, this'd be a good way to do it, yeah.

Comment: @Roger, then perhaps a more pertinent question would not start with `I've got a file ...`

Comment: It's Unix. Everything's a file :)